How far would a 2790 psi shockwave launch somebody
In my magic system people possess control over one concept such as fire, flesh, water, lightning, ice, etc. A major antagonist in the story possesses the ability to control sound to devastating effect. They awaken their abilities while playing football where they accidentally release a concussive blast of 2790 psi shock wave on a quarterback launching the mans body into the upper atmosphere. As this is his maximum limit I need to know how powerful a 2790 psi shockwave would be in its launching capabilities. So in summary how far would a 2790 psi cone of a shock wave accelerate a large adult male?

The man is 120 kg and has a surface area of 3 meters squared
The shockwave is radiated in a 100 meter cone cone instead of a burst
The sound controller is immune to the effects of such high sound
The football player will stay intact when hit with sound due to being imbued with temporary invulnerability
The energy for such an act comes from the energy of several quantum entangled stars so there is a super high energy limit
The energy is fully applied to the man with little losses
The exact distance is necessary to the story due to story reasons


The question a) appears to be incomplete, and b) a "230 decibel shock wave" is meaningless in Earth's atmosphere.

Wdym is meaningless cause a ton of tnt has is 240 decibles

@jdunlop is that better?

Not sure that "launch" is the most accurately descriptive word. Anatomize (or even atomize) might work better there.

The last sentence of the question still cuts off mid-thought, so I don't think this question is complete.

I think the consensus here is that what will happen is that the person will stop being a person and start being physics.

Or perhaps geography.

To the close voters why would you close vote and can I get some suggestions

What is the length of the cone

The close vote (not mine, but I may add to it) is for "Needs details or clarity", and the fact that the question still cuts off mid-sentence is probably a contributing factor.

Why did you edit and still leave the last sentence unfinished?

@Escapeddentalpatient. My wife asked for the papers

This is still missing information. Stop thinking about atmosphere for a moment and think about how you would use a 100 meter cone of Styrofoam. The cone is moved fast enough to impact the adult with the equivalent (ignoring some details) of 2790 psi. OK, does the cone keep on moving forward, or does it just stop when it impacts the adult? Does it matter if the cone is 100m long? Is it only 3m in diameter at the base? How much mass is behind the cone? Is the cone deforming as it moves forward? Now ask that about atmosphere, which acts the same way only with less density.


2790 psi is about 190 atmospheres, or about 190 kilograms-force per square centimeter.

The surface area of the target is given as 3 square meters; if the overpressure wave is coming from the front it will be acting on about half of that, so 1.5 square meters.

1.5 square meters is 15,000 square centimeters. Times 190 kilograms-force, that's 2,850,000 kilograms-force, or about 28,000,000 newtons.

The target's mass is given as 120 kg. Acceleration is force divided by mass, so 28,000,000 / 120 which is about 233,000 meters per second squared.

The overpressure wave is travelling at the speed of sound, or about 340 meters per second.

The final speed depends on whether the target is hit from the front or from below.

If the target is hit from the side, the target being shaped more or less like a human it is maybe 0.5 meters thick; the overpressure wave will trave 0.5 meters in about 1.5 milliseconds. The final speed is acceleration times the duration of the impulsion, or 0.0015 seconds times 233,000 meters per second squared, or about 350 meters per second (1,260 km/h, 783 mph).

If the target is hit from below, the duration of the impulsion will be about 4 times longer, but the force will also be 4 times smaller, because humans have a much smaller cross section in the transverse plane than in the frontal plane; so that overall the factors cancel out.



The human-shaped target will receive an initial speed of about 350 meters per second. A human-shaped object is not at all well suited to flying through the atmosphere at high speed, so that its speed will fall down very quickly to the terminal velocity which will be anything between 55 and 90 meters per second, depending on the attitude of the target.

Kinetic energy is mass times speed squared divided by two; given that the mass is 120 kg and after a very short time the speed will decrease to a value between 55 and 90 meters per second, the kinetic energy acquired by the target will be 190,000 to 490,000 joules.

Assuming that somehow the tricky magician arranges to use all this energy to propel the target up, the maximum height reached by the target will be about 160 to 400 meters (525 to 1,600 feet). Whether that's sufficiently upper atmosphere is up to debate.

If instead of up the target is propelled horizontally, then the calculation becomes much trickier, because we can no longer do a rough-and-ready estimation based on energy but we would have to take into account air resistance and friction with the ground. The distance travelled could be anything from less than a hundred meters through a forest to several kilometers on a nice smooth straight freeway.



Based you are the skibidi sigma of ohio w answer chat

Keep in mind that that acceleration is around 23,751 $g$-forces. Humans typically can't withstand more than half a dozen for very long...

@controlgroup: From the question: "The football player will stay intact when hit with sound due to being imbued with temporary invulnerability".

That's fair. But if you're willing to handwave invulnerability, you might also just as well handwave whatever distance is necessary. And "intact" might not necessarily be construed to also mean "alive"...
